# Why does by row mutate work with an even number but not an odd in R?

Tags: r

I have a function that is creating data frames for use by another function. It works fabulously if my initial input is an even number of parameters, but it breaks if it is odd. I do not at all understand the behavior.

To start, let's use two simple data frames: three_var and four_var - the number of variables refers to the variables between the "start" and "mid" variable.

```
three_var
  variable given total
1    start 100.0   100
2        a   0.5    50
3        b   0.7    35
4        c   1.2    42
5      mid    NA    42
6        x   1.0    42
7      end    NA    42

four_var
  variable given total
1    start 100.0 100.0
2        a   0.5  50.0
3        b   1.7  85.0
4        c   0.2  17.0
5        d   1.5  25.5
6      mid    NA  25.5
7        x   1.0  25.5
8      end    NA  25.5

three_var <- structure(list(variable = c("start", "a", "b", "c", "mid", "x", 
"end"), given = c(100, 0.5, 0.7, 1.2, NA, 1, NA), total = c(100, 
50, 35, 42, 42, 42, 42)), .Names = c("variable", "given", "total"
), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")

four_var <- structure(list(variable = c("start", "a", "b", "c", "d", "mid", 
"x", "end"), given = c(100, 0.5, 1.7, 0.2, 1.5, NA, 1, NA), total = c(100, 
50, 85, 17, 25.5, 25.5, 25.5, 25.5)), .Names = c("variable", 
"given", "total"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```

I can pass `four_var` through the following for clause and get an output.

```
for (i in 2:nrow(four_var)) {
     four_var$decrease[i] <- four_var$total[i-1] - four_var$total[i]
     four_var$increase[i] <- four_var$total[i] - four_var$total[i-1]
 }
four_var
    variable given total decrease increase
1      start 100.0 100.0       NA       NA
2          a   0.5  50.0     50.0    -50.0
3          b   1.7  85.0    -35.0     35.0
4          c   0.2  17.0     68.0    -68.0
5          d   1.5  25.5     -8.5      8.5
6        mid    NA  25.5      0.0      0.0
7          x   1.0  25.5      0.0      0.0
8        end    NA  25.5      0.0      0.0
```

However, when I pass `three_var`, I get an error:

```
for (i in 2:nrow(three_var)) {
     three_var$decrease[i] <- three_var$total[i-1] - three_var$total[i]
     three_var$increase[i] <- three_var$total[i] - three_var$total[i-1]
 }
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "decrease", value = c(NA, 50)) : 
  replacement has 2 rows, data has 7
```

This code does not look like it should depend upon the number of inputs. What am I missing?

Comment: It is not the correct way to create a new column in a data.frame. It works for `four_var` because `8/2` equals `4`. `i` is recycled. You can verify if if you set `i = 2`, run `four_var$decrease[i] <- four_var$total[i-1] - four_var$total[i]` and display `four_var`. You will see the recycling. In `three_var` case, `7/2` is 3.5. Recycling fails. Better to create column before the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not the correct way to create a new column in a data.frame. It works for `four_var` because `8/2` equals `4`. `i` is recycled. You can verify if if you set `i = 2`, run `four_var$decrease[i] <- four_var$total[i-1] - four_var$total[i]` and display `four_var`.

```
four_var <- structure(list(variable = c("start", "a", "b", "c", "d", "mid", 
"x", "end"), given = c(100, 0.5, 1.7, 0.2, 1.5, NA, 1, NA), total = c(100, 
50, 85, 17, 25.5, 25.5, 25.5, 25.5)), .Names = c("variable", 
"given", "total"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")

i <- 2
four_var$decrease[i] <- four_var$total[i-1] - four_var$total[i]
#   variable given total decrease
# 1    start 100.0 100.0       NA 
# 2        a   0.5  50.0       50
# 3        b   1.7  85.0       NA
# 4        c   0.2  17.0       50 <- recycling
# 5        d   1.5  25.5       NA
# 6      mid    NA  25.5       50 <- recycling
# 7        x   1.0  25.5       NA
# 8      end    NA  25.5       50 <- recycling


three_var$decrease <- NA
three_var$increase <- NA
for (i in 2:nrow(three_var)) {
     three_var$decrease[i] <- three_var$total[i-1] - three_var$total[i]
     three_var$increase[i] <- three_var$total[i] - three_var$total[i-1]
 }
three_var
#   variable given total decrease increase
# 1    start 100.0   100       NA       NA
# 2        a   0.5    50       50      -50
# 3        b   0.7    35       15      -15
# 4        c   1.2    42       -7        7
# 5      mid    NA    42        0        0
# 6        x   1.0    42        0        0
# 7      end    NA    42        0        0
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining this rather than just giving me the answer. I did not realize that i would be recycled at all in this case.